# Python Pandas: Apply function using column names as named arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Is there a way in pandas to apply a function to a dataframe using the column names as argument names?  For example, I have a function and a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
               'B':[1,2,3],
               'C':[1,2,3],
               'D':[1,2,3]})    
def f(A,B,C):
   #Pretend code is more complicated
   return A + B + C
```

Is there a way I can do something like

```
df.apply(f)
```

and have pandas match the columns to named arguments?

I know I can rewrite the function to take a row instead of named arguments, but keep in mind that f is just a toy example and my real function is more complicated

EDIT:

Figured it out based @juanpa.arrivillaga answer:

`df[list(f.__code__.co_varnames)].apply((lambda row: f(**row)), axis=1)`

Comment: ?df.eval('A+B+C')

Comment: Is there a way to do that without having to rewrite the function f?

Comment: the function f is just a toy example.  My real function is more complicated.

Comment: It's probably more helpful to be explicit with the example function.

Comment: Right now, your `apply` is acting column-wise. In that case it's far more logical to just pass it the Series as you have it. You could make it row-wise but honestly in most cases you can avoid looping with apply in favor of vectorized operations.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney why? They already give you a reproducible example.

Comment: `apply` doesn't work regardless of `axis`, because the function accepts named arguments, not rows.  Just using `apply` to sort of illustrated what I've tried so far and what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, building off of @juanpa.arrivillaga answer.

`df[list(f.__code__.co_varnames)].apply((lambda row: f(**row)), axis=1)`

Answer (score 7):

The function to apply `f` needs to accept either rows/columns, depending on `axis=0,1`, of `df` as an argument, not the column name. You can write a wrapper for this purpose.

```
def wrapper(x, A, B, C):
    return f(x[A], x[B], x[C])

df.apply(wrapper, axis=1, args=('A','B','C'))
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    6
2    9
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are interesting for "apply" function, here is the case

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                  'B':[1,2,3],
                  'C':[1,2,3],
                  'D':[1,2,3]})     


def func(row):
    row['result'] = row['A'] + row['B'] + row['C']
    return row

df.apply(func, axis = 1)


    Out[67]: 
       A  B  C  D  result
    0  1  1  1  1       3
    1  2  2  2  2       6
    2  3  3  3  3       9
```

## UPD

If you have to use function "f" and don't want to change it, may be this:

```
df['res'] = f(df['A'], df['B'], df['C'])
df

    Out[70]: 
       A  B  C  D  res
    0  1  1  1  1    3
    1  2  2  2  2    6
    2  3  3  3  3    9
```

Comment: That works, but is there anyway to do that without having to rewrite the function f?

Comment: That works and is simple, so upvoted!  But generally most functions can't operate on series', and my true function in particular has if statements in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way *in general*. However, if your column names alight *exactly* you can wrap the function in another function that splats the row argument into your function, because `Series` objects are mappings!

So given:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
...                'B':[1,2,3],
...                'C':[1,2,3],
...                'D':[1,2,3]})
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
>>> def f(A, B, C): return A + B + C
...
```

We could *almost* do:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: f(**row), axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/juan/anaconda3/envs/ecqm-catalog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6014, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Users/juan/anaconda3/envs/ecqm-catalog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 142, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/Users/juan/anaconda3/envs/ecqm-catalog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 248, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/Users/juan/anaconda3/envs/ecqm-catalog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 277, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: ("f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'D'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

If you know what the columns you need, you can select/drop to get the correct series:

```
>>> df.drop('D',axis=1).apply(lambda row: f(**row), axis=1)
0    3
1    6
2    9
```

Comment: Yeah I threw that column D in because there typically are extra columns.  I like the trick with the ** though